# How do you run the official GUI?

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui

The pull request for the official GUI [was recently merged](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/50ixic/first_gui_beta_coming_by_mbg033_%E8%B7%AF_pull_request_6/?ref=share&ref_source=link). How do you get the GUI running?

Comment: What is your OS ? Version/Distribution ?

Answer (score 14):

The instructions linked here will get the non-official build up and going on Ubuntu i386.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4yp52w/super_simple_build_instructions_for_the_monero/

```
# Early Monero-GUI setup and build instructions:

# For best results, I used Oracle's VirtualBox to make a virtual machine and loaded a fresh install with the latest Ubuntu 16.04 i386 iso. **NOTE** Be sure to have at least 15-20gb allocated for space on the virtual drive, and no more than 3gig of RAM for the VM (as for me it crashed with more than 3 gig of RAM).

# Ubuntu 16.04 i386 Monero GUI Install instructions (these are the exact instructions and links I used. The VM was set up on a Windows 7 installation)

# grab a copy of virtual box and follow the install instructions here http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox , and
# grab a copy of Ubuntu's latest iso if you don't have it yet, http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent

# after Ubuntu is installed and running, go into the command line and run these commands...
# update Ubuntu's repository
sudo apt update

#install git to download latest Monero source code from github
sudo apt install git

# install bitmonero dependencies to be able to compile Monero, taken from here: https://moneroexamples.github.io/compile-monero-09-on-ubuntu-16-04/
sudo apt install build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev pkg-config libssl-dev

# go to Ilya's repository where the most recent version is (you can run this while the previous command is running)
git clone https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core.git

# go into the repository
cd monero-core

# use the script to make sure everything is in order and compile the bitmonero libs necessary to run the GUI
./get_libwallet_api.sh

# install the GUI dependencies (this can be run while bitmonero is being compiled with the previous command)
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qttools5-dev-tools qml-module-qtquick-dialogs

# build the GUI
qmake
make

# To run the GUI, don't forget to have a bbitmonero client running in the background for the GUI to talk to, it's probably not necessary to have an updated blockchain, but if you have one on hand you can load into the machine it certainly won't hurt. The GUI should run without the node, but you still must follow all the steps listed, so this command is optional.
./bitmonerod --rpc-bind-port 38081

# go to the directory where the compiled client is
cd /release/bin

# run the GUI client
./monero-core
```

Comment: A link alone is not considered a [good answer](//monero.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Links may break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially. At least if you [include a summary](//monero.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), the answer can somewhat stand on its own.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to add the entire set of instructions because it is long and potentially messy. I'll edit it to include the instructions in full, but if you are unhappy in the first place, you should be editing the answer yourself as the content is already there.

Answer (score 3):

Clone the repository, run `build.sh` and hope it compiles in your system.

Otherwise, wait for the official binaries.

Answer (score 2):

There has since been an official beta release of the GUI.

You can download it [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/releases/tag/v0.0-beta-1) for Linux, macOs, and Windows.

More information can be found [here](https://getmonero.org/2016/12/22/monero-core-gui-beta-released.html) at getmonero.org.